# How do I check to see if three points form a straight line?

Tags: matlab

**Problem**: Create the function `mylinecheck(a,b,c,d,e,f)` which takes six inputs:
`a,b,c,d,e,f` which are real numbers, and `a,c,e` are not equal. The function must check if the three points `(a,b)`, `(c,d)`, and `(e,f)` all lie on the same line. If so, return a 1. If not, return a 0.

I think what I want to do is tell MATLAB to check if coordinates `(c,d)` and `(e,f)` are multiples of `(a,b)`, and then if not I will return a 0. If so, I will return a 1. If this is the right thought process, I'm not sure how to command MATLAB to do so. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That will only work if the line goes through the origin.

Comment: Broad hint: for all points to "lie on the same line", they must all obey the same equation `y = m*x+b`.

Answer (score 4):

The points `(x1,y1)`, `(x2,y2)`, and `(x3,y3)` lie on the same line if and only if they satisfy

```
a x + b y + c = 0
```

for fixed values of `a`, `b`, and `c` (I cannot get over your notation; sorry for the "confusion"), where `a` or `b` are nonzero. Hence they lie on the same line if and only if

```
a x1 + b y1 + c = 0         [x1 y1 1][a]   [0]
a x2 + b y2 + c = 0   <=>   [x2 y2 1][b] = [0]
a x3 + b y3 + c = 0         [x3 y3 1][c]   [0],
```

that is, the homogeneous linear system with the matrix

```
    [x1 y1 1]
X = [x2 y2 1]
    [x3 y3 1]
```

has a nonzero solution. This is possible only if `X` is singular. By eliminating the last column of `X` you can find that `X` is singular if and only if the matrix

```
Y = [x2-x1 y2-y1]
    [x3-x1 y3-y1]
```

is singular.

To reliably check for the singularity of a matrix in Matlab, you can use SVD or, equivalently, the function `rank`. Hence your function could be implemented as follows:

```
function [result] = mylinecheck(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3)

result = rank([x2-x1, y2-y1; x3-x1, y3-y1]) < 2;
```

Comment: How did you choose `3` in  `min(s) <= 3 * eps * max(s);` ?

Comment: @kkuilla Usually, the singular values which are smaller than the dimension of the matrix times the machine precision times the largest singular value are considered zero. I don't think it's important here but included for completeness.

Comment: Could you have done `length(s)` instead of `3` then? That makes sense If `3` would be arbitrary, then you are just playing with a "random" threshold and your answer has no advantage over @rayryeng's .

Comment: @kkuilla 1) `length(s)=3`. 2) There is a certain error analysis behind that "random" threshold. In addition, this criterion is exactly what is used by the Matlab's function `rank`. 3) SVD is one of the most stable algorithms in matrix computing and one of the most (or better, *the* most) reliable ways how to determine the rank in floating point arithmetic. While the numerically evaluated determinant can attain essentially arbitrary values for a pretty singular matrix, the ratio of the extremal singular values is always guaranteed to be close to the machine precision.

Comment: @kkuilla No problem, I've rewritten the answer anyway to hide any "random" thresholds elsewhere :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if points all fall on the same line (or are [collinear](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Collinear.html)), one of the classic methods would be to assume that each point forms a vertex in a triangle.   If the three points make the triangle such that the area is equal to 0, then the points would be collinear or form a line.  This can be done by checking the determinant of the following matrix:

```
[a b 1]
[c d 1]
[e f 1]
```

You can read the article on collinearity on Wolfram Mathworld here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Collinear.html (I also linked it above).

As such, your function simply needs to be:

```
function [out] = mylinecheck(a,b,c,d,e,f)

    D = [a b 1; c d 1; e f 1];
    out = det(D) == 0;
```

However, due to numerical imprecision, you may provide floating point numbers where the points are indeed collinear, but you may get a determinant that isn't equal to 0 (actually, perhaps a small number).  As such, one thing I can suggest is check to see if the determinant is less than a small number.  Something like:

```
function [out] = mylinecheck(a,b,c,d,e,f)

    D = [a b 1; c d 1; e f 1];
    out = abs(det(D)) < 1e-10;
```

`1e-10` is a small number which is `10^{-10}`.  We take the `abs` to account for both positive and negative determinants, so you would be checking collinearity and is true if:

```
 -10^{-10} < det(D) < 10^{-10}
```

However, with the comments made by Pavel, if points fall along the same line, if we decide to scale the coordinates, the determinant value will also increase in value as well.  One suggestion I have is to perhaps be more liberal with the threshold.  Make it larger.... perhaps something like `0.1`.

Comment: A small problem with the determinant criterion is that it is not independent of the scaling; if you scaled the coordinates, say, by a factor of `X`, the error in evaluating the determinant would scale roughly by `X^2`. If, e.g., `a=b=1`, `c=d=3`, `e=f=5`, determinant is about `1e-15` in double precision. Multiply now all coordinates by `1e6`, the determinant is about `1e-4` (all because of cancelation).

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel - Ah how true.  Well... given the wording of the question, I'm hoping that the coordinates won't be ridiculously large!  One way to combat this would be to increase the size of the threshold.  Using 0.1 with a scaling factor of `1e100`, it seems to work.

Comment: So would [`rcond`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rcond.html) be a better function since (I think) it is scale agnostic?

Comment: Another possibility: `rank([c-a d-b; e-a f-b])`