# Given two points, find if a third point is in the above or below the formed line

Tags: php, math, vector, google-cloud-vision

I have consumed the google cloud vision api to recognize a document with a table, but sometimes the image will be a little rotated, im triyng to get the value using the `boundingPoly` of the key i want, but how do i get it if it's not on the same `'y'`.

I was thinking of making a 'line' above and below the `boundingBox` and finding if the point is between that, but i dont know how to do it.

```php
[18] => Array
(
  [description] => Date
  [boundingPoly] => Array
  (
    [vertices] => Array
    (
      [0] => Array
      (
        [x] => 698
        [y] => 289
      )
      [1] => Array
      (
        [x] => 729
        [y] => 289
      )
      [2] => Array
      (
        [x] => 729
        [y] => 301
      )
      [3] => Array
      (
        [x] => 698
        [y] => 301
      )
    )
  )
)
```

```php
[66] => Array
(
  [description] => 25/03/2019
  [boundingPoly] => Array
  (
    [vertices] => Array
    (
      [0] => Array
      (
        [x] => 1007
        [y] => 290
      )
      [1] => Array
      (
        [x] => 1131
        [y] => 290
      )
      [2] => Array
      (
        [x] => 1131
        [y] => 307
      )
      [3] => Array
      (
        [x] => 1007
        [y] => 307
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check to see if three points form a straight line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28619791/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-three-points-form-a-straight-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given points `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`, you can determine whether a third point `(x3, y3)` is collinear as follows.
First, compute the slope `m1 = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)`.
Next, compute the slope `m2 = (y3 - y2) / (x3 - x2)`.
The lines are collinear if and only if `m1 = m2`. 
Collinear means they lie on the same line.
This fails only for vertical lines; those cases can be handled separately as follows: `x1 = x2 = x3`, then the points are collinear; if `x1 = x2` or `x2 = x3` but not `x1 = x2 = x3`, then the third point is not collinear with the first two.

---

Given lines `(m1, h1)` and `(m2, h2)`, you can determine whether a point `(x3, y3)` is "between" these lines as follows.
Compute `y1 = h1 + m1 * x3` and `y2 = h2 + m2 * x3`.
Then, the point is between the lines if and only if `y1 <= y3 <= y2` or `y2 <= y3 <= y1`.
2. If both lines are vertical lines `x = x1` and `x = x2`, then the point is between the lines if and only if `x1 <= x3 <= x2` or `x2 <= x3 <= x1`.
If exactly one of the lines is vertical (assume it's the first one for ease of notation), then compute `x2 = (y3 - h2) / m2`; then the point is between the lines if and only if either `x1 <= x3 <= x2` or `x2 <= x3 <= x1`.

(If one of your lines is vertical and the other is horizontal, I guess the only point in between them is their point of intersection).

Comment: Im sorry, im trying to understand the second formulae, but what is the `(m1, h1)`

Comment: @WeslleyRocha m1 is the slope of the first line, and h1 is the first line's y-intercept. Those two things uniquely define any (non-vertical) line.